# Query SharePoint List and write value

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I want to query a sharepoint list and return one row and write that row out.

Here is what I have in my ascx page

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td><SharePoint:FieldValue runat="server" FieldName="Name" Value="Name" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is what I have to retrieve my row

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
        if (list != null)
        {
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PatientID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + PatientID + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems();
            if (items != null)
            {
                Name = Convert.ToString(items[0]["Name"]);                      
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="">Name</td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Name" runat="server" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>



using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                {
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='PatientID' /><Value Type='Number'>" + PatientID + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

                        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);
                        if (items != null)
                        {
                            SPListItem item = items[0];
                            Name.Text = item["Name"].ToString();

                        }
                    }
                }
```